# How can I look up my created webpages on internet explorer 8 or older?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I am using windows7 and it supports only internet explorer 9. I work on web pages designing on my chrome browser. But you know, some of the CSS features dnt support in Enternet Explorer 8 or erlier. But when I trying to download Internet explorer 8 to my Win7 OS it never downgrade IE from 9th to 8th. Then how can I look up my created web pages on IE8 ? Plz help

Comment: @j08691 might be overkill. there are many software to do so.

Comment: I like BrowserStack http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: maybe you could try http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575 with that virtual machines they expire regulary so I don't know if they still work

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - overkill would be buying a new PC to test a browser. Virtual machines are cheap (i.e. free) and give you exact results.

Comment: VM is NOT free, license still counts, except you target open source OS.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Developer tools? Then change the "Browser mode" and "Document Mode" to check the web page behaviour in lower versions .

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. http://netrenderer.com/ to check all IE versions screenshoots
2. http://cloudinternetexplorer.com/ to check IE live (IE9 only)
3. https://browserling.com/ to check IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari versions
4. http://www.browserstack.com/ is commercial, but have a free trial
5. http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ is commercial, but have a free trial too
6. etc...

EDIT: I recommend, if you are using CSS3, to use http://css3pie.com/ is a super htc app, that make major CSS3 function to work in IE.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: You are almost welcome... +1 ?

Answer (score 0):

IETester allows you to run multiple versions of IE shells:

http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: Will try this 1. thnx :)